# Display updated values using JQuery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I am submitting a page using the Ajax POST.

I am using Datatables , whose value is populated depending upon a value selected from a Combo Box

I would like to refresh the page and display the updated values in the Datatables for the selected Combo box value.

How can i achieve this using JQuery.

PS : I am using Spring for controller purposes

Comment: **SOLVED !!!!!!**

Called a Ajax function to update the values for in the table. :)

Comment: Please post your solution as answer and accept it. This is the common approach to questions that were solved by their authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Parent-Child-DataTables.aspx . Here a child table is reloaded when row in the parent table is selected (looks similar to your problem)